# jQuery Custom Plugin Syntax

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm practicing making my own jquery plugin.  I can make simple plugins, but I'm getting more complicated now.

I want to create a plugin that listens for a form's submission, and validates all the inputs.  I know there's a few plugins out there that already do what I intend to do, but I'm interested in learning it myself now.

Here's my simple form:

```
<form id="testform">           
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="button" value="Validate" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#testform").validateMyForm();
   }); 
</script>
```

To me, this is the vanilla flavor to my form elements.  I didn't add any classes to the inputs, not other meta-data.
However, I intend to use meta-data that isn't typical, and pertains to my future form validation plugin.

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" validate="min:2,max55,msg:Invalid First Name" />
```

Of course, I'm sure the validate tag will have more options.

Here's the start of my plugin:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.validateMyForm = function( options ){
    // settings defaults
    var settings = $.extend({'addclasstoinput':''}, options);
    return this.each(function(){

    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Here's where I get confused.
The plugin is Meant to do it's magic when the Submit button is pressed, or basically when the form is submitted.

I've worked with code like this before:
    $("form.someform").submit(function(){ /* do whatever */ });
So I'm expecting this is what I need to do in my plugin.

Does this look correct to any jquery plugin veterans?

```
(function($) {
$.fn.validateMyForm = function( options ){

    // settings defaults
    var settings = $.extend({'addclasstoinput':''}, options);

    var alertElements = '';
    $(this).submit(function(){ 

        $('input').attr("validate").each(function() {
            // `this` is the div
            alertElements += $(this).attr("validate");
            alertElements += '\n';
        });
        alert(alertElements); // let's get a popup of the detected tags

    });

};
})(jQuery);
```

So far I'm getting an "undefined alertElements" error in my FF Error Console.
I'm also concerned I'm not using $(this) inside the plugin correctly. As I loop thru the form inputs, I see myself using $(this) to catch any "validate" attributes.  Is this how I should be coding it?

Comment: $(this) is not the div because you are calling the each on the string returned by the attr()-function.

Comment: Your plugin looks miserable :| 1. `this` inside `$.fn.xxxx` is already a jQuery object.  2. Your plugin allows only one use. The `alertElements` is never reset to an empty string (it should be declared within `submit`, anyways). It takes all input elements in the document, without including an option to reduce the set of input elements. --> Your plugin isn't very portable.

Answer (score 0):

I would go instance based there. Each form may have it's own options with this way.

```
$.fn.formValidation = function (options) {
return this.each(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    if (element.data('formValidation')) return;
    var formValidation = new formValidationInstance(this, options);
    element.data('formValidation', formValidation);
});
}
```

This code gives you the ability to instantiate your plugin and save itself to the element it has been called from. Once you created this, you need an instance code like this

```
var formValidationInstance = function (element, options) {
var elem = $(element);
var obj = this;

//default options
var defaults = {
        youroption : "defaultval"
}


// Merge options with defaults
var settings = $.extend(defaults, options || {});

this.settings = settings;

// Private method   
var init = function (elem, settings) {
          //do your init stuff here
    }

    // Public method
    obj.otherfunc = function() {            
          //do your other stuff here using 'elem' element.
    }

    var assignevent = function() {

         //assigning event is a little bit trickier
         // if sometimes you need to rebind your event, first unbind your previous one to prevent multiple executions.

         elem.unbind("submit").bind("submit",function(){

             //this event is out of this class scope, to get this inner methods first we need to reach its instance.

             var instance = $(this).data("formValidation");
             if (instance){
                   // if we got the instance saved inside this element, we can use it now
                   instance.otherfunc();  // Calling an public function. private won't work here.
             }
         });
    }


// init our plugin first:

init();
}
```

and wrap it all together inside (function($) { ... })(jQuery);

This is what I'm using when creating instance based plugins.